# How to make my TextView clickable

Tags: android

I am trying to make my TextView clickable. 
I have set setMovementMethod() with LinkMovementMethod.

```
myText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

But when I set myText value to 'cnn.com/money' or 'www.cnn.com/money'.Both are not clickable.
How can I make the text clickable (i.e. go to web browser for the link)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linkify:

```
myText.setAutoLinkMask(0)
Linkify.addLinks(myText, Linkify.ALL);
```

If you just wanted to have weblinks in your textview be picked up, (ie not email addresses or phone numbers), then do:

```
Linkify.addLinks(myText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html) for more cool stuff you can do with linkify.

Answer (score 0):

I would add

```
android:clickable="true"
```

to the XML for the TextView, then add an onClick handler pragmatically that pulls the text from the TextView and fires off a browser intent with it to be picked up by whatever browser the user chooses.